# How to obtain the path to a file located across different folder and comparing them by their date & time in batch scripts

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to obtain the latest path of a driver that has been installed recently using a batch script. Every time I install a driver, os creates a new entry for that driver in the file repository.
Now I am getting the list of all the paths for the driver.dll file available in different folders. At the end, I compare their date and time and obtain the path to the latest driver that has been installed recently.

```
:: Get the list of all the path to driver.dll available in FileRepository folder
set counter=-1
(for /d %%a in (C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\exampleDriver.inf_*) do (
    set /A counter=!counter!+1
    set driverlist[!counter!]=%%a\driver.dll
))

:: Identify path to the latest driver.dll
(for /l %%a in (0,1,!counter!) do (
    ::echo !driverlist[%%a]!
    for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4 delims= " %%a in ('dir /a-d /tc !driverlist[%%a]!') do ( 
        ::echo Created on: %%a, %%b
        if [%PATH_TO_DLL%]==[] (
            set oldDate=%%a
            set oldTime=%%b
            set PATH_TO_DLL=!driverlist[%%a]!
        ) else (
            if /I %%a geq oldDate (
                if /I %%b geq oldTime (
                    set oldDate=%%a
                    set oldTime=%%b
                    set PATH_TO_DLL=!driverlist[%%a]!
                )
            )
        )
    )
))
echo %PATH_TO_DLL%
```

The output of this scripts is:

```
latest path = C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\exampleDriver.inf_amd64_2e390485e03f89fe\driver.dll
```

But this is not the correct path of the driver.dll file installed recently.
Can anyone help me on this? I don't know what wrong i am doing.